# operand of type const void where arihmetic or pointer type required

Tags: ios, filestream, iostream, streamwriter

Why am i getting the error:
Operand if type const void where arithmentic or pointer type required to the following line:

//insert data at a specific position in a file

```
 NSData *chunk = chunkContainer; // some data
        NSUInteger insertPoint = chunkNo*512; // get the insertion point //
        // make sure the file exists, if it does, do the following //
        NSData *oldData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        // error checking would be nice... if (oldData) ... blah //
        NSOutputStream *stream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];
        [stream open];
        [stream write:(uint8_t *)[oldData bytes] maxLength:insertPoint]; // write the old data up to the insertion point //
        [stream write:(uint8_t *)[chunk bytes] maxLength:[chunk length]]; // write the new data //

//THE NEXT LINE IS THE LINE I AM GEETING THE ERROR AT 
  [stream write:(uint8_t *)[oldData bytes][insertPoint] maxLength:([oldData length] - insertionPoint)]; // write the rest of old data at the end of the file //
        [stream close];
```

Comment: How about `((uint8_t *)[oldData bytes]) + insertPoint`?

Comment: why +? it says now ERROR: expected identifier

Comment: `+` is pointer arithmetic.  It should work.  Oh well.

Comment: issue solved. i ll see if this method works for inserting values in a file